# real time data visualization - what is the best solution?

Tags: data-visualization, matlab

I'm looking for some advice:

Soon I'll have to perform some analysis of UDP data. I have a SW that is already recording this data and based on this I can do offline analysis. I'm looking for a solution for real time analysis.

The analysis is consists of some data manipulation (i.e. some cos, sin, matrix multiplication...) and displaying the data on graphs (some of them). The data arrives in 2 UDP streams.

For me the easiest way is to use matlab (as I have already the functions ready there / pretty quick development of new functions which I'll require), but it requires installation of matlab run time on the target machine - which is little problematic for me.

Is there any other option for this that can be developed with minimum effort?

Comment: I am not sure if this is helpful. We are using https://redash.io/ to visualize our data on various dashboards. We mainly need some easy line and pie charts. We're really happy with redash. It is definitely worth a look.